# Missing elements using BeautifulSoup and Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm attempting to grab some info off FB marketplace listings. I'm able to get about half of what I need, but some of the list items are not showing up.

This is javascript generated, so I'm using Selenium and a headless chrome driver. Even using WebDriverWait to make sure that it loads.

Not sure where to go from here.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options  
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException


CHROMEDRIVER_PATH = 'G:\WPy-3661\python-3.6.6.amd64\Scripts\chromedriver.exe'
options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(CHROMEDRIVER_PATH, options=options)

url = "https://www.facebook.com/marketplace/item/1894930974147050"
driver.get(url)
html = driver.page_source

try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, '_2pid')))
except TimeoutException:
    print('Page timed out after 10 secs.')

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
car_info=soup.find("div", {"class":"_2pid"})
print(car_info)
```

Results:

```
<div class="_2pid">
    <ul class="uiList _4kg _6-i _6-h _6-j">
        <li>
            <ul class="_6c32 uiList _4ki _509- _6-i _6-h _6-j">
                <li class="_6c33"></li>
                <li><span
                        style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; line-height: 16px; letter-spacing: normal; overflow-wrap: normal; text-align: left; color: rgb(28, 30, 33);">Driven 51,000 miles</span>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <ul class="_6c32 uiList _4ki _509- _6-i _6-h _6-j">
                <li class="_41ri"></li>
                <li><span
                        style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; line-height: 16px; letter-spacing: normal; overflow-wrap: normal; text-align: left; color: rgb(28, 30, 33);">Automatic transmission</span>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Expected:

```
<div class="_2pid">
    <ul class="uiList  _4ki _509-">
        <li>
            <div><span
                    style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; line-height: 18px; letter-spacing: normal; font-weight: bold; overflow-wrap: normal; text-align: left; color: rgb(28, 30, 33);">How This Price Compares</span>
            </div>
            <div><a target="_blank"
                    href="https://l.facebook.com/l.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.kbb.com%2F&amp;h=AT3_mCt8Kfo6wpXMZA11ocxcyOtEzcinSeOKsl1dQR174GFYDZPwWaDtQWWaJVU4aR5QCyfFXKjuNDNnE7ZsBQ2CTfsSOJZFRbCRf94-oiOl_VriQZcPPtNOMUZ1pSoa1PyohA"
                    rel="nofollow noopener" data-lynx-mode="hover">Kelley Blue Book® </a><span
                    style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; line-height: 16px; letter-spacing: normal; overflow-wrap: normal; text-align: left; color: rgb(96, 103, 112);">Private Party Value</span>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="_idm"><span data-hover="tooltip"><span class="_1y50"></span></span></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="_6cbr">
        <div class="_6cbi">
            <div class="_6cbj" style="left: -3px; background: rgb(175, 179, 185);">$14,100<span class="_6cbk"
                                                                                                style="left: -25.507px; background: rgb(175, 179, 185);"></span>
            </div>
            <span class="_6cbn"><span class="_6cbo">Low</span></span><span class="_6cbs"></span><span
                class="_6cbt"><span class="_6cbu">High</span></span></div>
        <h4 class="_6cbv">$21,213 – $23,102</h4></div>
    <div><span
            style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; line-height: 16px; letter-spacing: normal; overflow-wrap: normal; text-align: left; color: rgb(28, 30, 33);">Price range for similar Honda Pilot in excellent condition · <a
            target="_blank"
            href="https://www.facebook.com/business/help/1545716818882941">How It's Calculated</a></span></div>
    <div class="_1lil _3-8y _3-96"></div>
    <ul class="uiList  _4ki _509-">
        <li><span class="_3-96"
                  style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; line-height: 18px; letter-spacing: normal; font-weight: bold; overflow-wrap: normal; text-align: left; color: rgb(28, 30, 33); display: inline-block;">About This Vehicle</span>
        </li>
        <li class="_idm"><span data-hover="tooltip"><span class="_1y50"></span></span></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="uiList _4kg _6-i _6-h _6-j">
        <li>
            <ul class="_6c32 uiList  _4ki _509- _6-i _6-h _6-j">
                <li class="_6c33"></li>
                <li><span
                        style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; line-height: 16px; letter-spacing: normal; overflow-wrap: normal; text-align: left; color: rgb(28, 30, 33);">Driven 51,000 miles</span>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <ul class="_6c32 uiList  _4ki _509- _6-i _6-h _6-j">
                <li class="_41ri"></li>
                <li><span
                        style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; line-height: 16px; letter-spacing: normal; overflow-wrap: normal; text-align: left; color: rgb(28, 30, 33);">Automatic transmission</span>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <ul class="_6c32 uiList  _4ki _509- _6-i _6-h _6-j">
                <li class="_6c37"></li>
                <li><span
                        style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; line-height: 16px; letter-spacing: normal; overflow-wrap: normal; text-align: left; color: rgb(28, 30, 33);">17 MPG city</span>
                    ·
                    <span style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; line-height: 16px; letter-spacing: normal; overflow-wrap: normal; text-align: left; color: rgb(28, 30, 33);">24 MPG highway</span>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <ul class="_6c32 uiList  _4ki _509- _6-i _6-h _6-j">
                <li class="_6c1g"></li>
                <li><a target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/business/help/1545716818882941">Excellent
                    condition</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="_1lil _3-8y _3-96"></div>
</div>
```

The issue might be due to the info being within a subsection of the page that is scrollable. Need to scroll for the source code to be generated by javascript? Not sure how to do it if that is the case.

Comment: Scrolls shouldn't be an issue unless the page dynamically load more content as you scroll, you can verify that by using dev tools while scrolling. What I can think now is that: `DesiredCapability['pageLoadStrategy'] = "none"` before you generate your driver may help, also, you may potentially set screen size `driver.set_window_size`

Comment: It'd not loaded when scrolling. These didn't get it either. Thanks though!

Comment: In that case you would have to scroll, the way to do this is run `driver.execute(script)`, and you would need to call `element.scrolltop += 10` etc to scroll that element after you loaded the page.